# Time it takes a mass point to go down a curve under gravity

Tags: geometry, physics

An age old question. How to calculate the time it takes a mass point to go down a frictionless curve under gravity?

P.S. The curve is convex and smooth and can be of any kind of shape.

Comment: BTW, look up the [brachistochrone problem](http://www.hep.caltech.edu/~fcp/math/variationalCalculus/variationalCalculus.pdf).

Comment: That's the shortest time path. I'm asking for a general solution for any kind of curve.

Comment: The time is in there, you must have missed it. See my answer now.

Comment: But what if I want to use the time for further calculation? For example, can you use your formula to find a curve that it takes a mass point the same amount of time to travel under gravity as it would to travel a straight line? Suppose the curve and the line have the same starting point and end point.

Comment: What is your question here? With this problem, if you parametrize a curve you can find the parameters that will yield the given time $T$. It is the same answer, even though you are changing the question now.

Comment: Yes I changed the question to explore it a bit further. Given a certain time t, how to find a curve between two points that it takes a mass point t to travel?

Comment: This is not an effective use of [Mathematics.SE]. Please post a new question with the new problem.

Answer (score 2):

This is the well known brachistochrone (Greek for short time) problem.

The time it takes to transverse a small element ${\rm d}s$ is

$$ {\rm d}t = \frac{{\rm d}s}{v} = \frac{\sqrt{1+y'^2}\,{\rm d}x}{\sqrt{2gy}} $$

with the time found from the integral

$$ \boxed{ T  = \int \limits_{x_1}^{x_2} \dfrac{\sqrt{1+y'^2}}{\sqrt{2gy}} \,{\rm d}x } $$

NOTE that $y' = {\rm d}y/{\rm d}x$